# CSS transforms within CSS columns disappear (Chrome)

Tags: css, css-transforms, css-multicolumn-layout

I've come across what may just be a bug in **Chrome**, but I'm hoping to get another set of eyes on this, and hopefully tell me if I'm missing something here.

**The issue:**

I have some `<li>` tags that are spread over three CSS columns (`column-count: 3`), and each item has a `transform` property on it. When I then go to transform sub-items **within** these `<li>` tags, every sub-item that is *not* in the first column disappears.

Here's a built-out example on CodePen: https://codepen.io/andyranged/pen/WMdrxR

Again, this is only happening in Chrome. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the problem is your `transform: translateY(0px)` in `ul.main > li` which is a 2D transform...then you are using `rotateZ` in `ul.main ul a` which is 3D transform which causing this visibility issue...

So to resolve this either remove the `transform: translateY(0px)` from `ul.main > li` which I think is better as it has no mean to apply `translateY(0px)`...

..or apply `backface-visibility: hidden` to the `ul.main ul a` if you have any further plans to use `translateY(0px)`

```
ul.main ul a {
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(5deg);
  transform: rotateZ(5deg);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

**[Updated Codepen ▸](https://codepen.io/bhuwanb9/pen/jZYKxX)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is weird – in this particular case, it doesn't seem to be particularly related to the `rotateZ` being a 3D transform. If I changed those child `<a>` tags to simply `translateX(15px)` instead (which is a 2D transform), the problem persists. Either way, your answer is correct, since it was a `backface-visibility` issue in the end! By the way - I totally agree with you that a `translateY(0)` on the parent elements is useless (lol), but the reason it's there is because in practice, I was animating those elements in from `translateY(2em)` to `translateY(0em)`.

Comment: I'd also like to ask whether you think that behavior is still buggy... If it works in the first column, shouldn't it work in the subsequent columns with _no_ `backface-visibility` property? (assuming I'm only using 2D transforms)?

Comment: This solved my problem as well. I don't think the _problem_ is the mixed use of 2d and 3d transform, I think the browser should be able to handle it. I'd say it's a bug.

Comment: Just an update: it was indeed a bug. I filed a Chromium bug report, and it has since been resolved a couple versions of Chrome ago!